# Django - Validate search query within template

Tags: django

I need the search result to be validated together with the statement that it is a query inside the template.

So if the user is searching for another user and this user does not exist, it returns nothing. otherwise it returns the username of the user.

If request.user just checks the user that is logged in.

something like this

```
{% if request.GET.q and request.GET.q.is_authenticated %}
```

but this does not work :D Thank you

Can I use is_authenticated or is there a better way?

```
 <li class="dropdown-hover">
 <form class="form-inline">
 {% include "tweets/search_form.html" %}
 </form>

{% if user in request.GET.q.is_authenticated %}

<div class="dropdown-content x-card-4 x-bar-block" style="width:300px">
<a href='{{ request.GET.q }}'>{{ request.GET.q }}</a><br/>

{% else %}

<div class="dropdown-content x-card-4 x-bar-block" style="width:300px">
<a href='#'>No users found</a><br/>
{% endif %}
 </li>
```

---

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way, just do `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}`.

Comment: If request.user just checks the user that is logged in. I need to check the query if the user in that query is authenticated. 
If possible something in 1 sentence so that I can span the right dropdown.... something like this {% if request.GET.q and request.GET.q.is_authenticated %} but this does not work :D Thank you

Comment: Is there just one user in that query?

Comment: I need the search result to be validated together with the statement that its a query. So if the user is searching for another user and this user does not exist, it returns nothing. otherwise it returns the username of a user that exists

Comment: You should do this checking in your backend view and pass the result to the template through context.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add loginRequiredMixin in your class so it allow to perform tasks only if user is logged in otherwise it redirect to login page.

Comment: I need the search result to be validated together with the statement that its a query. So if the user is searching for another user and this user does not exist, it returns nothing. otherwise it returns the username of a user that exists

Comment: alright then in class base view set model=User and inherit DetailView. write function get_queryset (self,*args,**kwargs) to get the default query and overwrite it with yourown.  query.filter (username__contains='username'l)

Answer (score 0):

@andre If you want to show/hide html tags in a template to the guest/logged-in user, you can use this `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` or you want to show some pages to the logged-in user @tabish-manzoor's solution is great.

Comment: I need it to be: If a user searches another user the dropdown should display the search result (username of the user) if that username exist, otherwise "no users found"

Comment: @Andre Create one rest API(Django rest framework) that will give you filter users on the basis of the input field, call that API using ajax in your code at the time of input, and return result add in the dropdown.